# SSPI: user principle name WCF client

Tags: wcf-client, sspi

I am trying to access a wcf client.  I know people are getting information out of it right now, so I know it works.  My problem is I can't seem to get past it.  The service is a mutual certific service.  I have the appropriate certs in my personal stores on my local machine.  Even with that, I get the following exception:

```
 A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception
```

Searching deep into the exception and I see this:

```
Message : The target principal name is incorrect
```

How can I resolve this?  Do I need to impersonate the user the app pool is running under?  Do I need to add an Identity\ServicePrincipleName or Identity\UserPrincipleName?  Has anyone run into an issue similar to this?

Answer (score 7):

See my answer to a similar problem here: [netTCP binding Soap Security Negotiation Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683182/nettcp-binding-soap-security-negotiation-failed/16848782#16848782). This guidance should apply to other bindings, not just TCP.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference for others, I experienced this issue but the existing answers didn't help.

My issue was with the `userPrincipalName` being used for a service reference.

I had recently re-registered the service reference in order update it but it had overwritten the specified `userPrincipalName` in the log files with my email address:

```
<endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/XXXX"
  binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IXXX"
  contract="XXXServiceReference.IXXX"
  name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IXXXX">
  <identity>
    <userPrincipalName value="my@emailaddress.com" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

To rectify the issue, I simply changed the `userPrincipalName` to `localhost`, which it what it was previously:

```
<userPrincipalName value="localhost" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I regenerated the client and the endpoint in the output.config file now had  `<identity>
     <userPrincipalName value="Serviecname@companyname.com" />
 </identity>`
in the Endpoint Tag. So the new endpoint looked like -

```
 <endpoint address="net.tcp://machinename:6001/ReferenceDataService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConf" contract="IReferenceDataService" >
     <identity>
 <userPrincipalName value="Serviecname@companyname.com" />
```

This solved my issue

Comment: In case anybody isn't familiar with WCF -  I used svcutil.exe to regenerate the client, and the output.config was generated with it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I specified the server's username in the endpoint.  Not the client's username.  And it was a UPN, not a SPN.

```
new EndpointAddress(
    new Uri("net.tcp://server:1234/MyWcf/svc"),
        EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("username@domain.local"))
```

From what I understand, the client verifies that it's talking to the expected user.